# How to use seleniumbase on M1 Mac (Apple Silicon)?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, apple-m1, apple-silicon, seleniumbase

I am trying to use seleniumbase on an [M1 Mac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_M1) as a secondary test. But I keep getting:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'seleniumbase'
```

Seems like architecture issue?

Comment: Sounds like it isn't installed. Have you tried `pip install seleniumbase` ?

Comment: this following worked for me: pip install seleniumbase --user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following fixed the issue on M1 Macbook:

`pip install seleniumbase --user`